# is there single method for updating a resultset entry?

Tags: java, types, resultset

I can see so many update methods in for resultset based on the datatypes of the fields. Isnt there any single method for it? Or can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use updateObject I suppose. You give up type safety that way.